# Python Fabric local() missing statement after -exec

Tags: python, fabric

I'm having trouble with Python Fabric removing some local files. Yet, I found a related post on StackOverflow with a solution. But I am wondering why does adding `2>&1` at the end fix it?

I can run the following perfectly fine in my terminal:

`$ find app/views/ -type f -name '*%%.php' -exec rm {} \;`

However when I do a fabric call I get:

```
$ fab rmcache
[localhost] local: find app/views/ -type f -name '*%%.php' -exec rm {} \;
find: missing argument to `-exec'

Fatal error: local() encountered an error (return code 1) while executing 'find
app/views/ -type f -name '*%%.php' -exec rm {} \;'
```

**0:** Why does it require `2>&1` through Fabric, but not locally?

**1:** Why does this work through Fabric?

```
def rmcache():
    local("find {0} -type f -name '*%%.php' -exec rm {{}} \ 2>&1;".format('app/views/'));
```

**2:** But this does not work through fabric?

```
def rmcache():
    local("find {0} -type f -name '*%%.php' -exec rm {{}} \;".format('app/views/'));
```

Comment: Very strange. #1 doesn't work for me, however #2 does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0: `2>&1` redirects stderr to stdout which means that if your command is throwing an error fabric won't pick it up because it isn't being returned to fabric (See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/818284/537164) for more details on 2>&1).

1 & 2: My guess is that your code is throwing an error because `'app/views'` is a relative path and `find` requires the directory to exist, therefore you would have to run your fabric command from the directory that contains the app directory.  Try using `'/full/path/to/app/views'` to ensure you are using the correct directory.